# time complexity analysis with pseudorandomic function

Tags: java

i just struggle because i can not do a time complexity analysis for the last cycle where i add casually the edges with pseudorandomic function,here is the code:

```
SplittableRandom rnd = new SplittableRandom();

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjlist =  new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
    adjlist.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
    
Nodo[]nodi=new Nodo[n];
    
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
    nodi[i]=new Nodo(i);
}
    
for (int i = 0;i<n-2;i++){//O(n)//
    int j = rnd.nextInt(i,nodi.length);
    Nodo tmp = nodi[j];
    nodi[j]=nodi[i];
    nodi[i]=tmp;
}
    
for (int k =0 ;k<n-1;k++){//O(n)//
    int i = nodi[k].info;
    int j = nodi[k+1].info;
    adjlist.get(i).add(j);
    adjlist.get(j).add(i);
}
    
int mrim = m-n+1;
    
for (int k=0;k<mrim;k++){
    int i = rnd.nextInt(0,n);
    ArrayList<Integer> a = adjlist.get(i);
        
    while(a.size()==n-1){
        i = rnd.nextInt(0,n);
        a = adjlist.get(i);
    }

    int j = rnd.nextInt(0,n);
        
    while (i==j || a.contains(j)){
        j = rnd.nextInt(0,n);
    }
    adjlist.get(i).add(j);
    adjlist.get(j).add(i);
}
```

could please anyone help me to do this analysis ? this code  add casually edges after the creation of a random path between nodes in a graph reprsented in adjacency list.

i think that i have suppose something about the structure of the graph (if is dense or sparse) but i am in impasse

Comment: i know this is inefficient approach to add the last edges ,but i can not have another approach about this

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop until you get a random number that's suitable.

Instead, produce a list of all possible numbers in the range, remove those that are not allowed, then shuffle the list and use the first element.

Comment: in the two cycle?